# python-ffmpegで動画と音声ファイルを結合して一つの動画にしたい。

Tags: python, python3, ffmpeg, mp4

動画はVP9、音声はopusのコーデックのファイルをあまり劣化させず変換してMP4の動画形式（コンテナ）に入れたいのですが、ドキュメントを読んだのですが、どのようにコードを書いて良いのか分かりません。

ここを読むと特殊な設定をしないと動画が劣化するような事が書いてあってそれをPythonのラッパー上でどのように書くのか分かりません。
http://tech.ckme.co.jp/ffmpeg_vp9.shtml

```
instream_v = ffmpeg.input(videopath)
instream_a = ffmpeg.input(audiopath)
stream = ffmpeg.output(instream_v, instream_a, title, vcodec="copy", acodec="aac")
ffmpeg.run(stream)
```

ネットから拾ったコードでこれを上手くすれば動画を作成出来そうなのですが、mp4形式する記述が見つからず上記のコードが何を意味するのか詳しく分かりません。`vcodec, acodec`は元のファイルは何であれaacなどにエンコードするという事でしょうか？
ffmpegに詳しい方
よろしくお願いします。

**回答**
上記のコードのタイトルをmp4の拡張子まで含めて書けば、ffmpegで勝手に判断してファイルを作成してくれます。

Comment: 知識も経験も無い者ですが、検索してこんなのがあるようなので、出力ファイルの拡張子を`.mp4`、両方の`codec`を`copy`で試してみてはどうでしょう？ [Concatenating audio and video files without encoding using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61892237/9014308), [How to combine The video and audio files in ffmpeg-python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56973205/9014308), [webm to mp4 conversion using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18123376/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。読んでみたんですけど、わからないです。すいません。vp9の動画はmp4にそのまま入れても対応しているんですかね？？もしそうならエンコードなしでいけそうな気がします。

Comment: 最後の紹介記事の回答に有るので出来るのでは？ [Re-mux WebM to MP4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60443156/9014308) 他にこんな記事などにも情報があるようです。[ふたば☆ちゃんねるのWEBM：作り方とかエンコードとか気をつけること](https://ch.nicovideo.jp/ieno/blomaga/ar1463622), [Screencastify で録画した動画を mp4 に変換する #ffmpeg](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/convert-webm-to-mp4-by-ffmpeg/), [(FFmpeg) VP9 Vaapi encoding to a .mp4 or .webm container from given official ffmpeg example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55007246/9014308)

Comment: 上記のコードで拡張子はmp4を付与すれば自動的になりました。ありがとうございます。無事出来ました。

Comment: 良かったですね。出来れば結果やノウハウを自己回答してみてください。

Comment: 回答部分は質問に追記するのではなく、個別の回答として投稿してください。

Comment: 個別で作りました。すいません。